# How to retrieve the position of a textarea in AFrame

Tags: aframe

I was able to get the text value of my textarea by writing this line of code (thanks to Diego Marcos):

```
console.log("value="+els.components.textarea.textarea.value);
```

I now want to get the position of said textarea. The line of code:

```
console.log("value="+els.components.textarea.position); gives result=undefined.
```

console.log(getAttribute("position")) gives the result [object Object].

Comment: That's expected. You're getting an object with an x,y and z properties. To print it do `var position = el.getAttribute('position'); console.log('x: ' + position.x + ' y: ' + position.y + ' z: ' + position.z);`

Comment: That worked. Thanks, Diego!

Answer (score 0):

Posting Diego's answer:

> That's expected. You're getting an object with an x,y and z properties. To print it do var position = el.getAttribute('position'); console.log('x: ' + position.x + ' y: ' + position.y + ' z: ' + position.z);